# How to use more ngIf statements in angular5 efficiently?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-ng-if

I am a beginner in Angular development. Now using the *ngIf statements in my components.

When searching I found articles which suggests not to use logic in *ngIf statements.

Example 1:

> > `<user-component *ngIf="role==='user'"></user-component><guest-component *ngIf="role==='guest'"></guest-component> and so on`

Example 2:

> > `<div [ngSwitch]="typeOfUser"><user-component *ngSwitchCase="user"></user-component><guest-component *ngSwitchCase="guest"></guest-component><default-component *ngSwitchDefault></default-component></div>`

How can I use these statements for cleaner and performant angular application.

Attaching a reference article from free-code-camp,
[Best practices for a clean and performant Angular application](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/best-practices-for-a-clean-and-performant-angular-application-288e7b39eb6f)

Comment: The first case can be simplified to `*ngIf="role !== 'guest'"`.

Comment: *I found articles which suggests not to use logic in *ngIf statements*: not everything is about performance. They probably give that advice because it tends tomake code less readable, less testable, and promotes code duplication. If you think your code is readable enough, then it's perfectly fine, and won't cause any performance problem. You shouldn't preoptimize anyway.

Comment: BTW, the article you linked to explains it: *Why? Having logic in the template means that it is not possible to unit test it and therefore it is more prone to bugs when changing template code.". See, nothing to do with perfrmance. And BTW, it also gives an example showing how to refactor the code. Have you read it?

Comment: yes I read the article, but bit confused of using the ngIf statements in my components.

Comment: If suppose, I am having a 10 children components in parent component. I can write multiple ngIf statements in a single component, As article suggests, we will not able to unit test it. Then how can I use my child components without using *ngIf statements.

Comment: Again. Using ngIf statements is perfectly fine. The article you linked to never said to avoid ngIf statements. What is recommends is to avoid placing too much logic in the template, i.e. avoid long, complex angular expressions, which reduce readability and testability. Using `*ngIf="role==='user'"` is very readable and efficient. Move on.

Comment: May be I misunderstood the article and my doubt is clear now. Thank you @JBNizet

Answer (score 5):

> When searching I found articles which suggests not to use logic in *ngIf statements.

I understand what the author of the article was *motivated* by, but I have to warn you that this particular section titled "Avoid logic in templates" is poorly worded advise.

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/best-practices-for-a-clean-and-performant-angular-application-288e7b39eb6f

> If you have any sort of logic in your templates, even if it is a simple && clause, it is good to extract it out into its component.

That's not *completely* true.

I would *hate* to maintain any components developed by a person who *constantly* did this. Their components would be bloated with properties, and you would constantly be switching back and forth between the HTML file and the TypeScript source code to figure out what the *business logic* really is.

But, there is value in the advice because it's based upon a proven practice for source code in general. It's a practice that isn't about any particular programming language, and it relates to the problems of *if statements* in general.

For example;

```
    if(x > 1920 && y < 4 && p !== 'expand') {
         // do work
    } else {
         // do work
    }
```

In the above example, the logical condition is impossible to understand. The expression contains unidentifiable variables, magical literal values and multiple conditions. We could also see something like this in an Angular template as `*ngIf="x > 1920 && y < 4 && p !== 'expand'"`.

The recommended approach is to not write conditions like this, but to break down the expression into human readable terms that explain the business logic.

For example;

```
    const max_screen_size = 1920;
    const min_device_count = 4;
    const expanded_mode = 'expand';

    const valid_screen = screen_size > max_screen_size && device_count < min_device_count;
    const valid_mode = mode !== expanded_mode;

    if(valid_screen && valid_mode) {
       // do work
    } else {
       // do work 
    }
```

The above works in most programming languages, but this is difficult to do in Angular templates because we can not introduce new variables.

So what I think the author is recommending is that you introduce new properties in the component to make the *business logic* in the template easier to *read and maintain*.

> Having logic in the template means that it is not possible to unit test it and therefore it is more prone to bugs when changing template code.

Now that is completely **false**. You absolutely can unit test templates in Angular. You can test the contents, the conditions and the structure. I have no idea what he's referring to here.

I feel he's implying that having *business logic* in the templates makes a component more prone to bugs when changing the template, but this is a silly argument because if you move the *business logic* to the component you've just moved where *bugs* are prone...

> How can I use these statements for cleaner and performant angular application.

Try to use the template features relating to `*ngIf` instead of just adding **many** if conditions. The *least* used feature that I see on projects is the `else` condition.

For example;

```
    <div *ngIf="user_role === 'admin'>
         Admin features
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="user_role !== 'admin'>
         General features
    </div>
```

The above is a problem, because you have to now change **two** places if the business rules change. Use a `else` condition instead.

For example;

```
    <div *ngIf="user_role === 'admin; else general'>
         Admin features
    </div>
    <ng-template #general>
         General features
    </ng-template>
```

Now there is only one condition above, and if you have to change it you won't miss a second condition by mistake.

Also, use the `as` feature of `ngIf` for simplifying your templates (works great with the `async` pipe).

For example;

```
   <div *ngIf="data.user.permission">
        <span>{{data.user.permission.title}}</span>
        <span>{{data.user.permission.code}}</span>
   </div>
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
   <div *ngIf="data.user.permission as perm">
        <span>{{perm.title}}</span>
        <span>{{perm.code}}</span>
   </div>
```